# How to find count of records per week of given month in django 1.11?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, postgresql, django-1.11

I need to count the number of records per week of given month. 
I got count per month of given year using query as below

```
c = Cars.objects.filter(sold__year='2017').extra(select={'month':'extract(month from sold)'}).values('month').annotate(perMnth=Count('sold'))
```

How to find count per week of given month, that is like week wise count of month 'November' , like week1=10, week2=12,week3=5,etc

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Extract](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/database-functions/#extract) to do this action

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractWeek
from django.db.models import Count

Cars.objects.annotate(
    week_num=ExtractWeek('sold')   # sets week number for each row
).values(
    'week_num'
).annotate(
    count=Count('week_num')
)
```

note that `ExtractWeek` was introduced in django 1.11 so it won't work on older versions

Comment: but this gives count of all weeks, what i need is count of week of a particular given month. For example weekly count of month November 2017.

Comment: is there any way to get week numbers of a given month?

Comment: @user123 if you want to filter by month simply use `filter(sold__month=num)` before `annotate

Comment: yes I tried filter    (sold__year=2017,sold__month=11) but there is sum mismatchings in the count showing. In postgres I queried same thing date from monday-sunday, sunday-saturday, monday-monday,etc. but the annotate query & posgtres query are showing different counts..and i am checking it..

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly the same problem (aggregating by an arbitrary period) and I just end up using pandas.

[pandas how to use groupby to group columns by date in the label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40433717/pandas-how-to-use-groupby-to-group-columns-by-date-in-the-label)

Comment: please check my answer, it might be helpful.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I didn’t know that. However, in my case I had to group records by user specified ranges so it would be much harder to do with extract. Tho, still nice.